# How to set/flip bitfields in C

Tags: c, bit-fields

I am trying to have a `uint64_t` bitfield be all set to 0. Then when I call the function within the given string, and it matches with the static global array that I have set it will flip the bit to 1. Currently I have the following code but for some reason when giving it different strings it is following the same behavior. So for example when I input the following string of "ABC" it should be printing out `111000`. How would I get the following behavior.

```
const size_t SETSIZE = sizeof(uint64_t) << 3;
char key[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' }

uint64_t set_encode(char *st) {
    int i, j;
    uint64_t set = 0;
    int length = strlen(st);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (st[i] == key[j]) {
                printf("%c", st[0]);
                set = set | 1 << (SETSIZE - 1 - i);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lu\n", set);
    return set;
}
```

Comment: what is it printing? I would put SETSIZE in parentheses
#define SETSIZE (sizeof uint64_t << 3)

If you because look at the expansion of your set function:

set |= 1 << (sizeof uint64_t << 3 -1 - i)

You either put a parenthesis there or put it in the define. But what is it printing as of now?

Comment: The code does not have much to do with bitfields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple problems in your code:

```
const size_t SETSIZE = sizeof(uint64_t) << 3;
```

Bytes might not be 8 bits, you should use `const size_t SETSIZE = 64;` since the type `uint64_t`, if present, is defined to be exactly 64-bit wide with 2's complement representation.

```
char key[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' }
```

The initializer has 6 characters but the explicit size is set to `5`.  Use `char key[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };`.  Note that `key` is not a C string as not `'\0'` is present in the initializer. Note also that you have a missing `;` at the end of the initializer.

```
uint64_t set_encode(char *st) {
```

You do not modify the string pointed to by `st`, use `const char *st`

```
    int i, j;
```

`i` and `j` should be defined as `size_t` for consistency with `length`.

```
    uint64_t set = 0;
    int length = strlen(st);
```

The return type is `size_t` because the length of the string might be larger than the range of `int`. In your particular case it is not fundamental as the function is only useful for strings with at most 64 characters, and you should also test for that.

```
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
```

`j` should be compared to `sizeof(key)`.

```
            if (st[i] == key[j]) {
                printf("%c", st[0]);
```

You probably want to print `st[i]` instead of `st[0]`.

```
                set = set | 1 << (SETSIZE - 1 - i);
```

It would probably be more consistent to use the bits from the lowest value to the highest value, and `1` must be cast to `(uint64_t)` to avoid arithmetic overflow on `int` for strings longer than 31 characters (if `int` is 32-bit wide): `set = set | (uint64_t)1 << i;`. Note however that even with the cast, the shift operation is still undefined for shift amounts larger than 63 or negative.

```
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lu\n", set);
```

`set` is not necessarily a `long`. You can print it as an `unsigned long long` that is at least 64-bit wide: `printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)set);` Or you can use the format specifiers from `<inttypes.h>`: `printf("%"PRIu64"\n", set);`

```
    return set;
}
```

Here is corrected version:

```
const size_t SETSIZE = 64;
char key[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

uint64_t set_encode(const char *st) {
    uint64_t set = 0;
    size_t length = strlen(st);

    if (length > SETSIZE) {
        printf("string too long: %zd bytes\n", length);
        length = SETSIZE;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(key); j++) {
            if (st[i] == key[j]) {
                printf("%c", st[i]);
                set |= (uint64_t)1 << i;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%llu\n", (unsigned long long)set);
    return set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or-ing is coded with `int` rather than the hoped for `uint64_t`

`1 <<(SETSIZE-1-i)` result in type `int`.  Further, likely UB as some shift counts are certainly wider than `int`.

```
// set = set| 1 <<(SETSIZE-1-i);
set |= ((uint64_t) 1) <<(SETSIZE-1-i);
```

---

Questionable print specifier. `"%lu"` may not latch `uint64_t`.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

// printf("%lu\n",set);
printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", set);

// Perhaps print as hexadecimal makes more sense
printf("%" PRIX64 "\n", set);
```

---

Note that `key[]` is too small.

```
// char key[5] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'}
char key[5+1] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'}
// or
char key[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'}
```

And why print `st[0]`

```
// printf("%c",st[0]);
printf("%c",st[i]);
```

---

Even with repairs, OP's final goal is not clear nor obtained.